evince link handler for pdfs - open link to named destination
evince is my default pdf viewer.
If I click a link to file:///home/patrick/A.pdf, then evince will open and display A.pdf.
I have a pdf with named destinations in it. I would like to be able to click file:///home/patrick/A.pdf#B and it takes me to named destination B in file A. How can I enable this functionality?
evince --named-dest=B A.pdf works perfectly well but I want this to happen automatically when I click the link.
